# LateX rendering for both Java and Objective C

Tags: java, iphone, android, objective-c, latex

I'm looking for a **LateX library** to render formulas.

The project is an offline database of math\physic formulas for a Smartphone application. I need the application to be **not too heavy**, and that users can enter their own formulas. So i want the program to render written formulas more than to display PNG files that are heavier.

The second tricky part is that the application will be both on Android (my part) and IPhone (another developper will do it).

The database will be the same in the two cases (SQLite), so we need to render the same written formulas, and preferably it will be Latex. But it can be different libraries.

Do you have any idea ?

Comment: It is definitely not easy to interpret TeX without being TeX, so a general use LaTeX-rendering might be only possible by in fact running LaTeX. I'm not sure this is possible on your target platforms. Of course, there may be implementions for some subset of formulas (without all the *define your own commands* stuff and such). You may want to look how MediaWiki (in Wikipeda, for example) does its TeX-like formulas.

Comment: I know the question is too old but today I came to the same problem. So, If you already got the solution then please direct me. I want to do display maths formula written in LaTex in my iOS application

Comment: @milanpanchal Take a look at https://github.com/kostub/iosMath

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have a look at [MathJax](http://www.mathjax.org/). This Javascript library renders TeX commands into math formulas. This is becoming more and more popular, many science and mathematical journal websites are adopting it to render equations online.

Usually MathJax is applied to the entire webpage to render all the equations at once; it's perfectly fine for computers, but I found it's a bit slow on iPhone / iPad. I guess it's similar on Android.

You should be able to use just the rendering part without much performance penalty, though.

Anyway, don't re-invent the wheel; instead, please contribute to MathJax!

Comment: Ok i checked it's very easy to run javascript this way.
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

There is a project called "VerbTeX" which basically edits the latex file on the phone but the latex command is run on a server. Perhaps you can either get an agreement with them and convince them to have a PNG (or whatever) rendering as well or you can build your own server side latex rendering. Of course, this depends on whether a server side solution is acceptable to you.

Comment: yes we were thinking about doing a server to render the LateX. The problem is that it has to be rendered directly on the application. the goal is to have a direct acces to the formula you want.
Anyway i'll try to contact them !