# LaTeX or MathML to an image on Android

Tags: android, xml, graphics, latex, imageview

Are there any open source libraries for taking a LaTeX string or MathML xml string and creating an image without using the java.awt.* libraries?

I have tried JEuclid but I couldn't proceed after java.awt.image.BufferedImage couldn't be resolved in my android project.

At the moment I'm converting my own data input format into LaTeX,
then I'm converting from LaTeX to MathML XML using SnuggleTeX because the plan was to use JEuclid to convert MathML to a PNG image.

The PNG image is used to update an ImageView to display the input equation (nicely) to the user.

What options do I have left?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think there was a similar discussion:
[LateX rendering for both Java and Objective C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4981659/latex-rendering-for-both-java-and-objective-c)

Maybe mathjax helps?
http://www.mathjax.org/

Comment: Mathjax was the first thing I downloaded. At 27MB it's hardly portable. Also to extract the required functions from it would be hell as it has such a complex structure.

Comment: @ozzy you can shrink MathJax down to ~2MB, cf https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax/wiki/Shrinking-MathJax-for-%22local%22-installation. For a sample app using MathJax, see http://www.mathjax.org/community/mathjax-in-use/mathjax-in-use-instructions-and-how-tos/

Answer (score 0):

Maybe Python for Android and using python code for converting MathML to SVG, such as this one:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/svgmath/

I have used this Python code with XSL FO and SVG to do technical documents in PDF, the SVG generated seems to be compliant to web browsers with proper fonts around.

Answer (score 0):

Try this library: https://github.com/kexanie/MathView. It does not exactly returns an image, but it is able to render LaTeX in a WebView and supports both inline and display math. The library provides two LaTeX rendering engine options: KaTeX and MathJax.

[image: An example of using MathView in a ListView]

<sup>*This is an example of using MathView in a ListView*</sup>